# Specify level of contents table

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

In my document I have several chapters with sections and subsections. In the generated contents table, it would look like

```
1. Chapter
1.1 Section
1.1.1 Subsection
1.1.2 Subsection
2. Chapter
2.1 Section
2.1.1 Subsection
```

How can I specify, that the contents table only shows up to the sections level and excludes everything deeper (subsection, etc.).

So that it looks like:

```
1. Chapter
1.1 Section
2. Chapter
2.1 Section
```

Comment: Use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` in the preamble -- this will fix the toc level down to sections only (1 means section)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The counter `tocdepth` controls the depth of sectioning levels appearing in the `ToC`

Setting the `tocdepth` to the value `-2` is the usual way to hide everything (unless `memoir` class is used, then it's `-3`).

From `part` down to `subparagraph` the levels are `-1`, `0`, `1`,`2`, `3`, `4` and `5`.

Here, subsections shouldn't be entering the ToC, use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` (preferably in the preamble).

Don't forget to compile twice, as usual with ToC related - 'problems'

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{How to be seen}

\section{You see me}

\subsection{You won't see me in the Toc}

\end{document}
```

[image]